# Why pprof heap inuse_space less than container_working_set_size?

Tags: go, kubernetes, heap-profiling

I found in grafana that my pod <***-qkcdl> occupated about 1.0G of `container_memory_working_set_bytes`, and 1.4G of `container_memory_rss`;

[pods momery usage in grafana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZVh6.png)

[container_memory_rss of pod(max avg current)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WYjK.png)

and my query of `container_memory_working_set_bytes` and `container_memory_rss` is:

`container_memory_working_set_bytes{k8s_cluster="$cluster", namespace="$dept", pod=~'$pod', container=~"$container"}`

`container_memory_cache{k8s_cluster="$cluster", namespace="$dept", pod=~'$pod', container=~"$container"}`

then when I track the pprof heap inuse_space, it shows:

```sh
go tool pprof --inuse_space pprof http://{pod_ip}:8899/debug/pprof/heap
Fetching profile over HTTP from http://{pod_ip}:8899/debug/pprof/heap
pprof: read pprof: is a directory
Fetched 1 source profiles out of 2
Saved profile in {local_path}
File: {app}
Type: inuse_space
Time: Oct 15, 2021 at 6:38pm (CST)
Entering interactive mode (type "help" for commands, "o" for options)
(pprof)
(pprof) top10
Showing nodes accounting for 335.36MB, 91.58% of 366.19MB total
Dropped 195 nodes (cum <= 1.83MB)
Showing top 10 nodes out of 77
...
```

so, why my golang application use only 335.36MB heap space, but the grafana show about 1.0G of working_set_size and 1.4G of rss, what does the "335.36MB", "1.0G" and "1.4G" means ? why ?

PS: I know what the metrics means, but it does nothing to me

> container_memory_rss: The amount of anonymous and swap cache memory (includes transparent hugepages).

> container_memory_working_set_bytes: The amount of working set memory, this includes recently accessed memory,dirty memory, and kernel memory. Working set is <= "usage".

Comment: > `The heap profile reports statistics as of the most recently completed garbage collection; it elides more recent allocation to avoid skewing the profile away from live data and toward garbage. If there has been no garbage collection at all, the heap profile reports all known allocations.`  it is reasonable that heap prifile is small than working_set_size

Comment: Heap is not the only memory in use by the process. Stack can take up significant memory. It would be very inefficient if unused heap was immediately released to the OS. Even when it is released, the OS is not required to reclaim it. Memory management is very complex, and 2 completely different measurements cannot be compared without inspecting every detail in between.